# Related to/has to do with stealing

Tags: gerunds

Can "related to" and "has to do with" be used with gerunds?
▪︎ My idea [Related to/has to do with] stealing Mr. George's secret safe.

Comment: You've asked [a lot of brief questions recently](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a166442) with no apparent research effort. (That's probably why you've received so many DV's and CV's.) When you ask a question, [please explain the research that you've done to try to answer it on your own](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Both possible.  But you need an auxiliary verb to form "... is related to stealing ..."

Comment: Or "...which has to do with..."